# IndexError: list index out of range showPicture(sys.argv[1], strip)

Tags: python, led

i got a problem with a python script.
We wanted to do light painting and it all works except the script.
There's always that error. It's the last line in code. Without that line nothing happens. Here's the error:

`File "showImage.py", line 49, in <module>
    showPicture(sys.argv[1], strip)
IndexError: list index out of range`

Here's the code:

```
import time
from neopixel import *
from PIL import Image
import sys

# see also https://learn.adafruit.com/neopixels-on-raspberry-pi/overview

# LED strip configuration:
LED_COUNT   = 50      # Number of LED pix.
LED_PIN     = 18      # GPIO pin connected to the pix (must support PWM!).
LED_FREQ_HZ = 800000  # LED signal frequency in hertz (usually 800khz)
LED_DMA     = 5       # DMA channel to use for generating signal (try 5)
LED_INVERT  = False   # True to invert the signal (when using NPN transistor 
level shift)

# method to blank all LEDs
def blankLine():
for x in range(LED_COUNT):
strip.setPixelColorRGB(x, 0,0,0)
strip.show()

# method to resize picture and show in column per column on the led strip
def showPicture(filename, strip):
blankLine()
# open file
img = Image.open(filename).convert("RGB")

# resize file
newWidth = float(img.size[0])/float(img.size[1])*LED_COUNT
img = img.resize( (int(newWidth), LED_COUNT))

width = img.size[0]
height = img.size[1]

pix = img.load()

for x in range(width):
for y in range(height):
    strip.setPixelColorRGB(y, pix[x,y][0], pix[x,y][1], pix[x,y][2])
strip.show()
time.sleep(0.3)

blankLine()

# main function - start of the program - you have to provide an image name 
as an argument
# Create NeoPixel object with appropriate configuration.
strip = Adafruit_NeoPixel(LED_COUNT, LED_PIN, LED_FREQ_HZ, LED_DMA, 
LED_INVERT)
# Intialize the library (must be called once before other functions).
strip.begin()
showPicture(sys.argv[1], strip)
```

I don't know what's wrong? Solved

New Problem: The LEDs show wrong colors. But the strange thing is that this is only in this script. If using another script it shows the correct colors. For example when it should show purple it's blue.

Comment: Please show the Python code indented properly. All left aligned is unreadable.

Comment: New Problem = New Question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I still can't comment for now, I'm writting this answer:

sys.argv[1] refers to the filename you're giving your script when calling it.
How do you run your script ?

By running it like: 

`python my_script.py my_file_name`

you shouldn't get this error no more

As I see in your code it is specified that you should give the filename as an argument so you might already do so..?

Comment: As I answered the question you asked, I'd expect you to mark my answer as accepted.
For a new question you're supposed to open a new thread.